# table size difference. are both examples identical?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
tNum={[2]=true , [3]=true,[4]=true, [5]=true ,[6]=true }

#tNum-->0 



tNum={} 
tNum[2]=true 
tNum[3]=true 
tNum[4]=true 
tNum[5]=true 
tNum[6]=true

#tNum-->6
```

why such a difference in size?
are both examples identical?

Comment: Length is not defined for arrays with `nil`s inside.  This is "Unspecified behavior".

Comment: спасибо, Егор.Как это не определена? А что-же это как не определение размера : tNum={}

Comment: Hello @Egor again! I’d be interested in the ‘long story’ about why you consisently post answers as comments. Maybe it fits your own reasons, but affects the posts in general: to others the question appears unanswered or unresolved, and there can be no green checkmark to help others quickly looking for what’s right. That said, you know your stuff - Meta StackOverflow suggests that others take your kind of answer comments, copy them over as an answer and mark as Community Wiki. Work for others to do this, but maybe the best. It’s not about reputation, but rounding out a good post.

Comment: To follow up on what @EgorSkriptunoff said, there is nothing much to be learned by comparing unspecified behavior with unspecified behavior. Please [edit] your question with what your goal is.

Comment: @TomBlodget: I think it's valid to ask why a language feature works the way it does. Unspecified behavior can't be discovered by experimentation. Aside from the fact that it's a basic thing that Lua tutorials should teach, this is a legit question.

Comment: @luther Yes, there was something learned up to this point but it's not yet clear what the goal of the attempt to use # is.

Comment: @TomBlodget I'm not sure I understand. The question is narrowly focused on a single language feature, therefore it's widely applicable (duplicates notwithstanding). Treating it as an XY problem would essentially just add an extra question to the post. Are we not allowed to ask questions about language features?

Comment: @Brian - The answering on SO usually consists of two independent tasks: to give a quick help to the OP; and to write a complete answer for future SO readers having similar problem.  Both of these tasks are important.  But my replies are good only for the first task, but not for the second (SO has complex rules about what should a good answer look like). I'm posting my answers as comments because of they are just a temporary hints that may (or may not) lead to an answer.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for that clarification - that is a fair response. I will look closer at SO’s expectations for answers. I never thought it was complex, but perhaps I am missing some expected details.

Comment: The two examples (table literal vs. fields added one-by-one) are different in that the first adds elements to the hash part of the table, the second to the array part. A table literal with explicit integer keys (`{ [1] = 'one', [2] = 'two' }`) puts the fields in the hash part, at least in Lua 5.3, whereas a sequence table (`{ 'one', 'two' }`) puts fields in the array part, and adding integer-indexed fields one-by-one (`t[1] = 'one'; t[2] = 'two'`) can put fields in the array part. That might explain why the length operator gives two different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two tables are semantically identical, but using `#` on them is ambiguous. Both 0 and 6 are correct lengths. Here's [an abridged version of the docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7):

> The length operator applied on a table returns a *border* in that table. A border in a table `t` is any natural number that satisfies the following condition:
>
> ```
> (border == 0 or t[border] ~= nil) and t[border + 1] == nil
> ```
>
> A table with exactly one border is called a *sequence*.
>
> When t is not a sequence, #t can return any of its borders. (The exact one depends on details of the internal representation of the table, which in turn can depend on how the table was populated and the memory addresses of its non-numeric keys.)

This is an example of *undefined behavior* (UB). (That may not be the right word, because the behavior is partially defined. UB in Lua can't launch nuclear weapons, as it can in C.) Undefined behavior is important, because it gives the devs the freedom to choose the fastest possible algorithm without worrying about what happens when a user violates their assumptions.

To find a length, Lua makes, at most, *log n* guesses instead of looking at every element to find an unambiguous length. For large arrays, this speeds things up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you define a table as starting at index `[2]`, the length operator breaks because it assumes that tables start at index `[1]`.
The following code works as intended:

```
tNum = {[1]=false, [2]=true, [3]=true, [4]=true, [5]=true, [6]=true}

#tNum => 6
```

The odd behaviour is caused because when you initialize an array with `tNum={}` it initializes by assigning every index to nil, and the first index is `[1]` (It doesn't actually initialize every value to nil, but it's easier to explain that way). 
Conversely, when you initialize an array with `tNum={[2]=true}` you are explicitly telling the array that `tNum[1]` *does not exist* and the array begins at index 2. The length calculation breaks when you do this.

For a more thorough explanation, see [this section](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html) of the lua wiki near the bottom where it explains:

> For those that really want their arrays starting at 0, it is not difficult to write the following:

```
days = {[0]="Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"}
```

> Now, the first value, "Sunday", is at index 0. That zero does not affect the other fields, but "Monday" naturally goes to index 1, because it is the first list value in the constructor; the other values follow it. Despite this facility, I do not recommend the use of arrays starting at 0 in Lua. Remember that most functions assume that arrays start at index 1, and therefore will not handle such arrays correctly.

The Length operator assumes your array will begin at index `[1]`, and since it does not, it doesn't work correctly.

I hope this was helpful, good luck with your code!

Comment: thanks, but I know that. I will clarify the question: why in the second example the length is 6?

Comment: how to explicitly determine the length of an array in the second example?

Comment: @PavelT to correctly calculate the length of the array in the second example, you could loop through the array and keep a running count of how many keys have a value that is not `nil`.

Comment: **`#` don't do that unless your table has a _[sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7)_.** (A table doesn't have a "start"; The sequence of a table, if it has one, starts at the number key 1. "array" is a foreign term [and if you get into the Lua internals, actually means something else there].)

Comment: `tNum = {}` does not initialize every index to `nil`; it creates an empty table, with no elements in the array or hash parts of the table. I verified this with the library [getsize](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize). (To actually initialize all elements to `nil` would use a huge amount of memory and time.)

Comment: @cyclaminist I understand how this works that it does not actually initialize every value to nil, but it's easier to explain this way.